# Python debugging

Tags: filetype-python, debugging

Is it possible to debug Python scripts line by line using `:Termdebug`?

`:help termdebug-customizing` says, that you need a debugger that is "fully compatible with gdb". Is there a debugger for Python that is compatible (using the GDB/MI interface)?

Or are there other alternatives?

Comment: I don't have the experience to answer you but the plugin python-mode has a feature which allows you to use breakpoints in python see [here](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/blob/develop/doc/pymode.txt#L249) they also mention the following debuggers: pdb, ipdb, pudb.

Comment: @Jakube did you figure out how to do this using Vim's `:Termdebug`? I am also very interested in how this works without using a bunch of plugins out the gate.

Comment: @FilBot3 From what I was able to collect, all the Python debuggers are incompatible with the GDB interfaces, so you can't use them with `:Termdebug`. You can debug Python with GDB itself, however then you are working on the C-level of the Python application.
There is one way that allows you to work with the actual Python code in GDB (see this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB9rPdMRxIA), however I haven't tried that yet, so I can't tell from experience.

Comment: I sounds a little annoying, since you need to use the `py-` prefix everywhere (`py-up` instead of `up`), but in general that approach should work also nicely with `:Termdebug`.

Comment: Posted a similar question up on Reddit too. https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/jg91dt/using_termdebug_for_pythons_pdb_examples/

Comment: @Jakube It would be awesome if you could post a self-answer with your findings! Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For me [vimspector](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector) looks amazing, and has out-of-the-box Python support.

Comment: Currently, it is really the best one. Based on VS-Code debugger.

Comment: vimspector support for neovim is currently experimental.

Comment: Cool. I use regular vim so it never occurred to me.

Answer (score 10):

There are alternatives.

Plain ol' [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) can be integrated into vim with

- [vimpdb](https://github.com/gotcha/vimpdb)
- [vebugger, etc](https://www.raditha.com/blog/archives/vim-and-python-debug/)

(My own favourite) [pudb](https://pypi.org/project/pudb/) can be integrated with

- [pudb.vim](https://github.com/SkyLeach/pudb.vim)
- [vim-pudb](https://github.com/KangOl/vim-pudb)

And the popular [ipdb](https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/) can be [integrated](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/blob/master/README.rst) with

- [vdebug](https://github.com/vim-vdebug/vdebug)
- [ipdb_breakpoint](https://gist.github.com/berinhard/523420)

Comment: vimpdb seems to support python 2 only https://github.com/gotcha/vimpdb#requirements

Comment: This also doesn't answer the OP's question of how to use the built-in Vim functionality. From what I see these plugins all use something that is outside of the Vim `Termdebug` native funcionality

Answer (score 2):

You could simply make shortcuts on python files that imports `pdb` and add a `pdb.set_trace()` etc.

But I use **PUDB** (that is the same, but with syntax highlight and all good graphical stuff) with the command `:term python -m pudb %`. It basically opens a new split window with the debug, the call stack...

I found that simple and convenient (and I remapped it on `<f6>`)